# ng- repeat is displaying rows equal to no of properties and not even displaying data on html view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="addr in addrShipData">
     <input type="radio" name="resp1" ng-checked='true'/>
      {{addr.addressLine1 +","+addr.addressLine2+", "+addr.city+ ","+addr.state+", "+addr.country+", "+addr.zipCode+","+addr.contactNum}}
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a>Edit</a>
</div>
```

js code:

```
 var dataObj = [];
  var shipDataObj = [];
  //var addrShipData =[];
  function shipData(shipDataObj){

      for(i=0;i<shipDataObj.length;i++){
          dataObj.push(addressLine1 = shipDataObj[i].addressLine1);
          dataObj.push(addressLine2 = shipDataObj[i].addressLine2);
          dataObj.push(city = shipDataObj[i].city);
          dataObj.push(state = shipDataObj[i].state);
          dataObj.push(country = shipDataObj[i].country);
          dataObj.push(zip = shipDataObj[i].zipCode);
          dataObj.push(contactNum = shipDataObj[i].contactNumber);
      }
  }
   appServices.getAddress(userData.customerId).then(function (data){

                    if (data){  
                          console.log(data);
                          $scope.shipDataObj = data;
                          shipData(data);
                        console.log("dataObj properties: " + dataObj);
                        $scope.addrShipData = dataObj;
                        console.log($scope.addrShipData);
                     if ($scope.addrShipData){
                                storeLocally.set('shipInfo :', $scope.addrShipData);
                          }
                          else{
                                $scope.addressError = "No Address Found!";                            
                          }         
                    console.log("address info:- " + $scope.addrShipData);
                    }
               }),
                function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 500) {
                      $scope.addressError = "Oops! No Address Found!";
                    };
                }
```

In js file I debug the code I am getting all values in $scope.addrShipdata in HTML view I am not getting any value.

i am getting o/p like this

on console:
1234 waller ave,suite1,fremont,California,USA,246326,213-435-4365

on html view: it is displaying blank.
   O ,, , , , , Edit
   O ,, , , , , Edit
   O ,, , , , , Edit
   O ,, , , , , Edit
   O ,, , , , , Edit
   O ,, , , , , Edit
   O ,, , , , , Edit

I am not getting any error either.I don't understand where is problem in code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rn3ewy1e/ if you could make a fiddle, that would help us solve your issue better

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created correct object definition which you are expecting in `ng-repeat` tempalte. Also you should create a whole object and push it to `dataObj` which will basically add object with new properties.

**Code**

```
for (i = 0; i < shipDataObj.length; i++) {
    dataObj.push({
        addressLine1: shipDataObj[i].addressLine1,
        addressLine2: shipDataObj[i].addressLine2,
        city: shipDataObj[i].city,
        state: shipDataObj[i].state,
        country: shipDataObj[i].country,
        zip: shipDataObj[i].zipCode,
        contactNum: shipDataObj[i].contactNumber
    });
}
```

Comment: @Pallavi does it helped?